# Multiple many-to-many relationships with a related_name of "+" result in the wrong query set

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that has two many-to-many relationships to the `auth.User` class, like:

```
class Indicator(models.Model):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="+")
    enemies = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="+")
```

The related_name is set to "+" [so that there's no backwards relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), i.e. I don't need `u.friends_set` and `u.enemies_set` if u is a user.

Adding, removing, and clearing 'friends' and 'enemies' works fine - if I check directly in the database (i.e. not through Django) I can see the changes reflected as I would expect.  However, if I get the query set through Django, I'm given the 'enemies' list whether I use `i.friends.all()` or `i.enemies.all()` (assuming `i` is an Indicator instance).

If I examine the ManyRelatedManager, I see that the `through` attribute is correct, which (if I understand correctly) is what allows add/remove/clear to work correctly:

```
>>> i.friends.through
<class 'project.app.models.Indicator_friends'>
```

However, the `get_query_set` method [basically](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/db/models/fields/related.py) gets the superclass (the User Manager) and calls filter on it with kwargs `i.friends.core_filters`, which is `{'+__pk': 404L}` (if the Indicator ID is 404).  The core_filters are the same for both "friends" and "enemies", which explains why I incorrectly get the same query set for both.

I can work around this (without setting a related_name): instead of `i.friends.all()` I can use:

```
[friend.user for friend in i.friends.through.objects.filter(indicator__id=i.id)]
```

However, that's hardly elegant.

1. Is this a limitation of Django's "set related_name to '+'" system?  (I couldn't find that documented anywhere) - i.e. that you can only use '+' once per distinct object/object pair?
2. Is this a Django bug (i.e. something to [report](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket))?
3. Is there a better way to work around this issue?

<sub>(Django 1.3 - I haven't tried trunk, but from reading the code it appears to have the same behaviour, with Python 2.7).</sub>

Comment: On trunk, I can't even build 2 m2ms with `related_name='+'` without validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at django/db/models/fields/related.py, it appears that the related_name = '+' option is really tested with a last character string slice in ManyToOneRel.is_hidden(). So simply appending a '+' to any string should do the trick, allowing you to have unique names in a single model and still have the backwards relationships ignored.

Answer (score -1):

you could always set your own query to the database directly. I believe the queryset does in fact think the indicator are the same. I am not sure how friends and enemies interact, but perhaps you can just query there specific id's instead.